# Python openCV maximum video duration

Tags: python, opencv, video, set, frame

I'm having some trouble reading entire durations of AVI videos using openCV (tested with both 2.4 and 3) and Python 2.7. The duration of the videos are around 20 minutes.

After a certain number of frames, I get an empty frame and a false flag meaning the frame could not be read. The way I am reading the frame is by setting the frame number using either the "CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES" or "CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC".
However, when I open the video with any other player (VLC, Windows Media Player) it plays the entire duration just fine.

As stated above, the problem occurs both with openCV 2.4.11 as well as 3.0.0-rc1.

I ran a test, where I read frames until the above happens, both setting the frame using time and frame number. The results are below.

The code is here,

```
pathname = "C:\\videos"

# get all videofiles
videofiles = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(pathname)) if file.endswith(".avi")]

nofalse = 0
v = 0
for vf in videofiles[1:]:
    v += 1

    # Test using frame number for seeking to frame
    # Open video file
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(pathname, vf))
    totalnoframes = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    frange = np.arange(0, totalnoframes, 100)
    for f in frange:
        cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, f)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret is False:
            break
    # close video file
    cap.release()

    # Test using time for seeking to frame
    # Open video file
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(pathname, vf))
    totalnoframes = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    totaldurationMS = 1000*totalnoframes/cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
    trange = np.linspace(0, totaldurationMS, totalnoframes)[::100]
    for t in trange:
        cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, t)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret is False:
            break
    cap.release()

    # print results
    vf = "Video %1.0f" % v
    print "%s:\t%1.0f\t%1.2f\t%1.0f\t%1.2f" % (vf, t, t/np.float(totaldurationMS), f, f/np.float(totalnoframes))
```

And the results are here.
First number column is last readable frame in milliseconds, second column shows rate of total frames read using time, third column is last read frame in number, and again the rate of read frames.

It seems like the upper frame number limit is around 14000, and no video with less total frames display the same limitation in reading the frame.

Has anyone any idea why this is happening? I've spend days trying to figure this out, no luck. ANY help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Video 1:    940046  0.69    14100   0.69

Video 2:    980045  0.68    14700   0.68

Video 3:    973372  0.59    14600   0.59

Video 4:    940047  0.70    14100   0.70

Video 5:    953370  0.54    14300   0.54

Video 6:    940063  0.95    14100   0.95

Video 7:    506733  0.99    7600    0.99

Video 8:    1040047 0.70    15600   0.70

Video 9:    806733  1.00    12100   1.00

Video 10:   940056  0.85    14100   0.85

Video 11:   620066  0.99    9300    0.99

Video 12:   880066  0.99    13200   0.99

Video 13:   953371  0.56    14300   0.56

Video 14:   1026727 0.90    15400   0.90